# Writing to a File - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that writes a listing of things to a `*.txt` file, and everything appears to be all good and well but nothing is written in the `txt` file. Any help is appreciated. I won't post my code on here because it's only a small fraction, but I'm using a formatter in the form `Formatter fileMaker = new Formatter("file.txt");` and then I would do something like `fileMaker.format(%s, String str);` but nothing turns up in the file? Thanks for the help.

Hopefully this little bit might help, maybe I'm doing something wrong that I don't see, but I declared it as private static Formatter fileMaker; in the class and then I implement it like below.

```
fileMaker.format("%s%d\n", "#flightCount", flights2.size());


    for(int i=0; i<flights2.size(); i++){
        fileMaker.format("%s %s%s%d%d %d ", "#newFlight", flights2.get(i).getSourceAirport(), flights2.get(i).getDestinationAirport(),
                flights2.get(i).getTakeoffTime(), flights2.get(i).getLandingTime(), flights2.get(i).getCapacity());
    }
```

Comment: Even if your code is a "Small fraction" you should post it. How are we supposed to know what is wrong with your program without the code?

Comment: you need to post up more info about what you have tried so far I guess\

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter fileWriter= new PrintWriter("my-file.txt");
fileWriter.println("Content");
fileWriter.close();
```

Comment: When I switched from Formatter to PrintWriter it said I had a NullPointerException which I don't understand why that happened, any thoughts?

Comment: @BrendanCameron What? Do you mean that this code gave you a null pointer exception? Do you want to show us what you tried?